# Bootstrap row-fluid .split

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, split, gutter

I need to create a row-fluid columns without gutter on my project, but I cant customize bootstrap because I need to gutter elsewhere.

I'm new on bootstrap and I came from Kube (http://imperavi.com/kube/).
There it was working like that:

---- create a column like span6 from bootstrap with gutter.

If I want to remove the gutter simple add:

      ------ now the columns do not have gutter separing them.

I want to do something like that to bootstrap or maybe create a row-fluid-split class, but how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove gutter by adding new class, let's call it `.no-gutter`.

That class have this properties:

```
.no-gutter .span4 {
    margin: 0;
    width: 33.3333333333%;
}
```

Then, you will add this class in HTML markup like this:

```
<div class="row-fluid no-gutter">
    <div class="span4">First</div>
    <div class="span4">Second</div>
    <div class="span4">Third</div>
</div>
```

And here is [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2jZvH/1/)

If you need gutter elsewere, than simply don't add this class.

Note that you must set this class for all `.spanX` bootstrap classes, where `X` is number from 1 to 12.